# How can I access angular2's Http service before I call bootstrap()?

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, angular2-services

I need to figure out if the user is authenticated or not so when the root component is bootstrapped it will forward the user to `/signin` or load whatever page they requested. (I plan on doing that by injecting a service with a boolean if it needs to sign on before making any requests).

Angular's docs mention a "Platform Injector" or a "Root Injector". Can I access this to get a Http object? or is it created when bootstrap is called and I need to create my own injector from scratch to get Http?

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?

Comment: @Thibs nope I haven't

Answer (score 1):

Before bootstrap the http module is not registered as a valid provider, so you can't use DI to instantiate it.

It's possible that you can find a way to instantiate it manually by importing Http and do

`var http = new Http(..)`

but you would have to satisfy the input arguments and I am not sure if it's recommended to try to work with modules before the application is in a stable bootstrapped state.

To keep this simple my recommendation would be to do the pre angular check using some other simple http implementation like jquery etc

Comment: I assume it's possible to create an injector yourself and pass HTTP_PROVIDERS and request Http from it.